# How to make a chunk of code that makes attributions in a dataset parallelized?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, sumo

I'm working on a simulation of car messaging using `SUMO 1.3.1` and python's `traci` module in `Ubuntu 18.04.4`. Every car has its own dataframe of messages with the rows being the other vehicles' IDs in the simulation and the columns being the time, they are created at the begging of the code and filled with 0's (this can't be changed because it was asked for me to be done this way).

Every car is individually checked to see if other cars are in a given range to send them a message, if they are it initiates a process in which the program changes the value on the receiver's table respective to the current time and the sender's ID to 1 or 2, depending on a chosen chance.That chunk of code was running really slow because it was using just one CPU.
What I want to achieve is to use parallelization to fasten this process.

What I've done until now is starting to use the multiprocessing library, the problem is that the code is running even slower now. I don't know if it was me misusing the module or maybe there is another module more fitting to this kind of situation.

Here is the code used before multiprocessing:

```
for car in car_vector:
                dist = np.sqrt((pos_vector_x - traci.vehicle.getPosition(car)[0])**2 + (pos_vector_y - traci.vehicle.getPosition(car)[1])**2) #creates a vector with all distances from the cars in the simulation and the car being used in the moment
                for j , receiver in enumerate(dist): #generates a list of tupples, with j being an index for the distances, j is used to know which car correspond to that distance in the car_vector
                    if receiver < 30 and receiver > 0.5: #the distance defined is 30 meters and the condition of being higher than 0.5 comes to stop the car from sending messages to itself
                        dic_frames[car] = contamination(step - 2,car_vector[j],dic_frames[car])
```

With the contamination function being:

```
def contamination(time,receiver,data_msgs): #pass on the contaminated colors to the non-contaminated cars
    threshold_lost_message = 0.2
    is_critical = random.randint(1,100) == 1 
    if random.random() > threshold_lost_message:
        if is_critical:
            data_msgs.loc[data_msgs.IDs == receiver,str(time) + '00ms'] = 2 
        else:
            data_msgs.loc[data_msgs.IDs == receiver,str(time) + '00ms'] = 1 
    return data_msgs
```

And here is the code "using" multiprocessing:

```
for car in car_vector:
                processes = []
                dist = np.sqrt((pos_vector_x - traci.vehicle.getPosition(car)[0])**2 + (pos_vector_y - traci.vehicle.getPosition(car)[1])**2) #creates a vector with all distances from the cars in the simulation and the car being used in the moment
                for j , receiver in enumerate(dist): #generates a list of tupples, with j being an index for the distances, j is used to know which car correspond to that distance in the car_vector
                    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=multiprocessing_func, args=(car,j,receiver,dic_frames,car_vector,step))
                    processes.append(p)
                    p.start()
                for process in processes:
                    process.join()
```

With the `multiprocessing_func` being:

```
def multiprocessing_func(car, j, receiver, dic_frames, car_vector, step):
    if receiver < 30 and receiver > 0.5:
        dic_frames[car_vector[j]] = contamination(step - 2,car,dic_frames[car_vector[j]])
```

Is there a way I can make this process use more than one CPU even though it only makes attributions? Doing it for more than one car at once maybe.

Comment: Can you share more of the code? How many elements are there in `dist` (and therefore how many processes) ?

Comment: There are 300 cars in the simulation, and dist vector is the distance of all cars to a chosen one, including the distance to himself

Answer (score 1):

You could try parallelizing in the outer loop because multiprocessing has a considerable overhead.

```
def func(car,pos_vector_x,pos_vector_y,dic_frames,car_vector,step):
     dist = ...

for car in car_vector:
    processes = []
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=(car,pos_vector_x,pos_vector_y,dic_frames,car_vector,step)
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()
for process in processes:
    process.join()
```